# WebStorm with Babel not working with import statements

Tags: webstorm

I'm using WebStorm 2017.1.3, although also tried with latest EAP, and i can't get `import from` statement to work. I just keep getting the following error:

```
import Utils from './utils'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

In my `packages.json` i have `babel-cli`, `babel-preset-env` and `babel-preset-es2015` defined. I have followed various blog posts and videos but still get same error.

ES6 is enabled in settings and i tried adding Babel file watch as per documentation but nothing seems to work. This feels like it should be a lot easier and just work, so i must be missing a important part of the jigsaw.

Does anyone have a working step by step, from fresh project, how to guide in configuring webstorm to work with `import` ?

Some places say use file watch, others say just to change project configuration interpreter to use `babel-node`. Other say must use Gulp... very confusing.

Thank you.
fLo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make things clear: this is not about configuring WebStorm, error comes from Node.js interpreter that runs your code. Node.js still doesn't support ES6 modules natively (actually, no JavaScript runtime currently supports them - ECMAScript does not define a "Loader" specification which determines how Modules are inserted into the runtime. The Loader spec is being defined by WHATWG, but is not yet finalized). So, to get ES6 imports/exports accepted, you need using transpilers. Current industry standard is Babel

The most simple way to make it work is the following:

- install babel in your project using `npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-env`
- create a `.babelrc` file in project root dir:

  { "presets": ["env"] }
- in your Node.js Run configuration, pass `-r babel-register` to Node:

[image]

With this configuration, your code will be transpiled on-the-fly by Babel, no file watchers, etc. are needed

Comment: awesome answer, I wish I could upvote you more than once!